# Access the Name of all files in folder using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me if there is a way to get the list of files in current folder. The current folder is the folder from where my .html file is executing. This will be running at server side probably if necessary.

I have googled everything and got to know there are some ways to do it with FileSystemObject but I am not a big fan of it. I have no problem is giving credentials if required.

Comment: I'd use some server-side language (e.g. php) to output all filenames in a folder to the JS. Otherwise, I'm not aware of any JS Crawler.

Comment: I agree with FabrícioMatté. this likely needs to be down some some server side scripting like php or .net

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an server side language for that like php, asp.net or jsp . JavaScript cannot access files it work on client side.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no way to do that just with Javascript. Javascript runs on the client which has no access to the file structure on your webserver.

You will have to run some kind of server-sided code to pass the list of files to your script. There is a myriad of possible technologies for solving this problem. PHP, JSP, ASP... whatever you already have available or which tickles your fancy.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server side language like Asp/.net or PHP.

In C# (ASP.Net) you can use the example found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) on getting files recursively. Just change `Console.WriteLine`  to `Response.Write` (not exactly that simple but close).

In PHP you can follow [this example](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-list-all-files-in-a-directory/)

If you use a server side language probably is not going to be a need to use javascript/ajax if all you want to do is disaply the files. If you do both languages I mentioned support writing to the document at render time. Or you can point an ajax call to one of these pages, but the output would have to be in JSON.

Unless you have a **server-side** script you won't get the information you need. **Client-side scripts** have no knowledge of **server-side** anything (including file structure)